# Passing dynamic url parameter to a function without implicit typing (next.js typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, graphql

Using **useRouter** to a function strictly receiving *string* type parameter produces following error:

> Type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Is there a way how to **fix the error without implicit typing?**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useBlogQuery } from '@graphql/generated'

const router = useRouter()
const blogId = router.query.blogId

const BlogQuery = useBlogQuery({
    variables: {
        id: blogId
    },
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a useful type-checking error.

Consider:

1. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) `router.query.blogId = undefined`
2. [www.example.com/?blogId=1&blogId=2](http://www.example.com/?blogId=1&blogId=2) `router.query.blogId = [1, 2]`
3. [www.example.com/?blogId=1](http://www.example.com/?blogId=1) `router.query.blogId = 1`

You can do this if you are 100% sure cases 1 & 2 will never happen:

```
const blogId = router.query.blogId as string;
```

But probably better to add some logic around `blogId` being either `undefined` or an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I throw an error when blogId is an array? As it is unwanted behaviour

Comment: That's a great question. To be honest, how likely is this case in practice? And if you throw an error, what then? An ErrorBoundary reporting to Sentry (for example)? How about trying to pass to `useBlogQuery` an undefined an array to see what happens - maybe it will throw. It's completely up to you really, don't think there's a catch-all answer here.